# Rails Delegated Types Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the Rails 6.1 [DelegatedType feature](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html), but I'm not sure what the migrations should look like for their example:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  delegated_type :entryable, types: %w[ Message Comment ]
  delegate :title, to: :entryable
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  def title
    subject
  end
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  def title
    content.truncate(20)
  end
end
```

Would you use `t.belongs_to :entry` in the message and comment migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "delegating fields" (which are the same as polymorphic entity_type, entity_id) should be on the delegating model. It uses [the same polymorphism mechanism](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html#method-i-delegated_type) under the hood.

So on your entries table:

```
def change
  create_table :entries do |t|
    t.references :entryable, polymorphic: true
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: So what would be the migration on the Comment / Message models? Any reference to `entries`? Presumably not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confused on this topic. In the given scenario, you need to play the same like `**polymorphic association**`. You need to create a separate table for each model, and the `Entry model` will share its common attributes with messages and comments. Both Message and Comment models can have their own attributes as well.

If you use  `delegated_type` instead of the common `polymorphic association`, you can manage some complex features easily, like handling pagination, creating messages, comments and many more.

You will have three tables in your example.

1. **entries:** which can have some common attributes and -:

> ```
> def change
>   create_table :entries do |t|
>     t.references :entryable, polymorphic: true
>     t.timestamps
>   end
> end
>
> entryable_type, it will save the table name. (They can be messages.) 
> eentryable_id -> it will save the id of (message/comment); hence, we assume it will have messages in type, and here it will have message.id
> ```

2. **messages**

> ```
> def change
>   create_table :messages do |t|
>     t.string :subject
>     t.timestamps
>   end
> end
> ```

3. **comments**

> ```
> def change
>   create_table :comments do |t|
>     t.string :content
>     t.timestamps
>   end
> end
> ```

**Note:** You can take a look at the given link to understand more about the topic: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html.